# Is there a free method to share a USB device from a hyper-v host to a guest VM?

Tags: usb, virtualization, virtual-machine

I have a requirement to attach a USB device to a hyper-v host, and get it connected to a guest VM.

Looks like there are hardware solutions, or software solutions cost over $100, but the only free/opensource thing I can find is USB/IP. This seems to have been ditched as last update was 2011, and only a Linux server app was built, so wouldn't fit my scenario.

I saw some mention of using enhanced sessions, but I tried briefly with an iPhone and this did not seem to appear. In addition, I assume it requires me to have a constant enhnced session window connected to a VM (which in itself I would expect to be a security concern), and it must also mean that if the host restarts, the connection needs to be restored manually?

Is there currently any other free method of achieving this desired behaviour? (This is soo soo easy in ESXi, but due to my limited hardware setup, I cannot switch to ESXi at this stage of the game.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Samba would be a good alternative. You would then be able to access the USB device on the network, assuming your VMs are able to communicate on the network with your Hyper-V host.